# Does uproot4 not support tree.pandas.df(）function anymore?

Tags: root, uproot

I used to retrieve pandas dataframe from ROOT file using tree.pandas.df() function in Uproot4(2 years ago). However, I got the below errors when I ran my code recently. Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
f = uproot.open(inputFile)
treeName = "myTreeName"
tree = f[treeName]
myDf = tree.pandas.df('branchName',entrystop=nEvent, flatten = False)
```

AttributeError: 'Model_TTree_v19' object has no attribute 'pandas'

Answer (score 1):

In Uproot version 3, a special function named `TTree.pandas.df` created Pandas DataFrames.

In Uproot version 4 (and above), all of the functions that produce arrays have a `library` argument that specifies which library to use to represent the arrays. `library="pd"` makes Pandas DataFrames.

This change is described in the [Uproot 3 → 4 cheat-sheet](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot3-to-4.html#removed-features), the new argument is described in several places in the [Getting Started Guide](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html), as well as in all the reference documentation for array-fetching functions, such as [TTree.arrays](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TTree.TTree.html#arrays).